# Google AdMob not showing the advertisement in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I have used this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0,0);

 self.adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                              origin:origin]
                autorelease];

NSLog(@"%lf %lf ",self.adBanner.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);

self.adBanner.adUnitID = kSampleAdUnitID;
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
[self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
}
- (GADRequest *)createRequest {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

// Make the request for a test ad.
request.testing = YES;

return request;
}

#pragma mark GADBannerViewDelegate impl

// We've received an ad successfully.
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
 NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

This code is not giving any error.Nor it run/show the advertisement.What to do?Did i make any mistake in the code??I have set the adUnitID also.I am not getting my mistake.Please can anyone help me?Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of your `kSampleAdUnitID`?  Did you replace it with your AdMob publisher ID?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
    // Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

// Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
self.adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                origin:origin]
                 autorelease];
self.adBanner.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,50);
```